Formik values not saving in redux persist slice
store:
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

//SLICES
import mainLayoutReducer from "./mainLayoutSlice";
import userDataReducer from "./userDataSlice";
import schedulePeriodReducer from "./schedulePeriodSlice";
import loadingReducer from "./loadingSlice";
import draftDataSlice from "./draftDataSlice";

// API
import { tmsApi } from "../api";
import { daDataApi } from "../api/thirdPartyApis/daDataApi";

import {
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";

import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedMainLayoutReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig,
  mainLayoutReducer
);

const persistedDraftReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig,
  draftDataSlice
);

const persistedLoadingReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, loadingReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    // PERSISTED SLICES
    mainLayout: persistedMainLayoutReducer,
    loading: persistedLoadingReducer,
    draftData: persistedDraftReducer,
    // schedulePeriod: persistedSchedulePeriodReducer,

    // SLICES
    userData: userDataReducer,
    schedulePeriod: schedulePeriodReducer,

    // API
    [tmsApi.reducerPath]: tmsApi.reducer,
    [daDataApi.reducerPath]: daDataApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    })
      .concat(tmsApi.middleware)
      .concat(daDataApi.middleware),
});

export default store;

slice:
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  draftData: null,
};

export const draftDataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "draftData",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setDraftData: (state, action) => {
      state.draftData = action.payload;
    },
    clearDraftData: (state) => {
      state.draftData = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { setDraftData, clearDraftData } = draftDataSlice.actions;

export default draftDataSlice.reducer;

component:
const isDraft = location.search;

const draftData = useSelector((state) => state.draftData.draftData);

const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: isDraft
    ? draftData
    : {
      ...mainInfoValues(employeeInfo),
      ...vehicleInfoValues(employeeInfo),
      ...docsValues(employeeInfo),
    },
  onSubmit: // here onSubmit func
)}

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(setDraftData(values));
}, [values]);

return(
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Section overflow="inherit">
      {(() => {
        switch (step) {
          case 1:
            return (
              <MainInfo
                values={values}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                setValues={setValues}
                touched={touched}
                errors={errors}
                handleBlur={handleBlur}
                isStepOneEmpty={isStepOneEmpty}
                resetForm={resetForm}
                handleStep={handleStep}
              />
            );

          case 2:
            return (
              <VehicleInfo
                values={values}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                setValues={setValues}
                touched={touched}
                errors={errors}
                handleBlur={handleBlur}
                isStepTwoEmpty={isStepTwoEmpty}
                resetForm={resetForm}
                handleStep={handleStep}
              />
            );

          case 3:
            return (
              <AttachDocs
                values={values}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                setValues={setValues}
                touched={touched}
                errors={errors}
                handleBlur={handleBlur}
                isStepThreeEmpty={isStepThreeEmpty}
                resetForm={resetForm}
                handleStep={handleStep}
              />
            );

          default:
            break;
        }
      })()}
    </Section>
  </form>
)

I am trying to save values from formik to persist slice, everything ok, until redirect to another page and refresh it. When I come back my slice is empty, but if refresh current page with form, everything is ok and slice not empty.
Steps:

Make some changes in values at form
Slice fullfiled
Redirect to another page
Refresh page
Back to page with form
Slice is empty


Issue
I believe the issue is that your persisted reducers all use the same persistence key property so they end up overwriting each other.
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root", // <-- key => "persist:root"
  storage,
};

const persistedMainLayoutReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig, // <-- key <= "persist:root"
  mainLayoutReducer
);

const persistedDraftReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig, // <-- key <= "persist:root"
  draftDataSlice
);

const persistedLoadingReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig, // <-- key <= "persist:root"
  loadingReducer
);

Solution Suggestions
Use separate persistence keys for each slice reducer
const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: "root", // <-- key => "persist:root"
  storage,
};

const persistedMainLayoutReducer = persistReducer(
  rootPersistConfig, // <-- key <= "persist:root"
  mainLayoutReducer
);

const draftPersistConfig = {
  key: "draft", // <-- key => "persist:draft"
  storage,
};

const persistedDraftReducer = persistReducer(
  draftPersistConfig, // <-- key <= "persist:draft"
  draftDataReducer
);

const loadingPersistConfig = {
  key: "loading", // <-- key => "persist:loading"
  storage,
};

const persistedLoadingReducer = persistReducer(
  loadingPersistConfig, // <-- key <= "persist:loading"
  loadingReducer
);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    // PERSISTED SLICES
    mainLayout: persistedMainLayoutReducer,
    loading: persistedLoadingReducer,
    draftData: persistedDraftReducer,
    // schedulePeriod: persistedSchedulePeriodReducer,

    // SLICES
    userData: userDataReducer,
    schedulePeriod: schedulePeriodReducer,

    // API
    [tmsApi.reducerPath]: tmsApi.reducer,
    [daDataApi.reducerPath]: daDataApi.reducer,
  },
  ...
});

Use single persistence configuration and whitelist/blacklist the reducers you want to persist.
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // PERSISTED SLICES
  mainLayout: mainLayoutReducer,
  loading: loadingReducer,
  draftData: draftDataReducer,
  // schedulePeriod: schedulePeriodReducer,

  // SLICES
  userData: userDataReducer,
  schedulePeriod: schedulePeriodReducer,

  // API
  [tmsApi.reducerPath]: tmsApi.reducer,
  [daDataApi.reducerPath]: daDataApi.reducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  // Only persist these root reducers
  whitelist: ["mainLayout", "loading", "draftData"],
};

const persistedRootReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig,
  rootReducer
);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedRootReducer,
  ...
});


wow, it's worked, how simple and great, thanks for helping me again, Drew

One more problem in persist redux i faced, it is that in my form user can upload photo, and i think that serialized redux doesn't accept file in slice, maybe i should asked backend to help, for example upload photo to server and take url from response and than saved it in my draft slice

Sorry, probably i shouldn't ask this in the comments.

@DavidAbramov Yeah, Redux recommends storing only serializable values... Redux-persist needs serializable values because it JSON stringifies the store values. You can use transforms to help here though. I've not ever used transforms though so I might not be great help. You may also want to consider Base64 encoding/decoding your image files in the UI so you are only storing a Base64 string value in the store and then normal persistence flow should just work as expected.
